# React native ios push notifications have uppercase font

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, local, uppercase

I have a trouble with react-native local push-notification in iOS. All symbols in the notification text are in uppercase.
This is a code I used to schedule a notificaion:

```
PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
  fireDate: new Date(Date.now() + 60000),
  alertTitle: 'test alert',
  alertBody: 'test alert body',
});
```

You can see how it looks like on the picture attached.
I've got the same behavior on both my device and an emulator. Should I tweak any configuration option? Am I missing something? Thanks.

react-native version: 0.50.0
[uppercase-notication-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njGRq.png)